# Error while aligning text after a word

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I want to align text after some words. I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440439/219947) by @Torbjørn T. But there were error messages. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
        \textcolor{blue}{\textit{Name of the Experiment:} & Frequency Stability Study of a Power System blah blah blah}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The error messages are as below:

```
line 9: Missing } inserted. \end{tabularx}
line 9: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tabularx}
line 9: Missing } inserted. \end{tabularx}
line 9: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tabularx}
line 9: Missing } inserted. \end{tabularx}
line 9: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tabularx}
line 9: Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
```

How can this be solved?

I am using MiKTeX and PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Can show an image or sketch of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't enclose different cells in the same `\textcolor` command.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Like the one [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440436/align-text-after-a-word/440439#440439). Instead of black, the text would be in blue or any other color.

Comment: @campa, thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your problem is that you cannot open text color with `\textcolor{blue}{` and then start the next cell (with `&`). You have to close `\textcolor{blue}{}` first then start the next cell.

Either you wanted do to the first column *Name of the Experiment:* in blue then you have to do it like this, and close the textcolor earlier:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
         \textcolor{blue}{\textit{Name of the Experiment:}} & Frequency Stability Study of a Power System blah blah blah
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

or you wanted to have all the text in the table blue. Then you wrap the table in a seperate group like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begingroup %%start wrapper group
    \color{blue} %%assign textcolor

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
    
         \textit{Name of the Experiment:} & Frequency Stability Study of a Power System blah blah blah
    \end{tabularx}
\endgroup%%end wrapper group
\end{document}
```

Have a look at the [xcolor documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) - you can also change the background color of the rows.